# Problem using a npm package in React - says "TypeError: require is not a function"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, package

I'm trying to use the package [lastfm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lastfm) within a React app.
I have installed it with

```
npm install lastfm
```

The official doc says it should be used like this :

```
var LastFmNode = require('lastfm').LastFmNode;

var lastfm = new LastFmNode({
  api_key: 'abc',
  secret: 'secret'
});
```

And this is how I use it in my React code :

```
  import {LASTFM_API,LASTFM_API_SECRET} from "./Constants";
  import {LastFmNode} from 'lastfm';

  export class Lastfm {
    static scrobbleTrack(track): void {
      var lastfm = new LastFmNode({
        api_key: LASTFM_API,
        secret: LASTFM_API_SECRET,
        useragent: 'appname/vX.X MyApp'
      });
    }
  }
```

Which fires this error (from the package) :

> TypeError: require is not a function at lastfm-request.js:3

I'm quite new to React and NPM.
I wonder if there is some kind of incompatibility ?

How could I make this work ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The package is to be used on Node server and not on React App.

**EDIT**
Hi, sorry i cannot comment because my points are less.
You can not use that one as well because that is also a node package. 
If you see a syntax where you have to use:
 `require('something');` 
usually means it is a node package because in React, your syntax for importing is something like this: 
`const abc from 'xyz';`

Comment: Hi, ok, that is why it does not work... How do you see that ?  Thanks !   +Could I use this one then ?  https://github.com/maxkueng/node-lastfmapi

Comment: Could I use this one then ?  https://github.com/maxkueng/node-lastfmapi